# Use OpenId Connect for authentication only

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, openid-connect

OpenId Connect adds authentication to the OAuth2 protocol. OAuth2 is a protocol used for authorization. But what if I'm only interested in authenticating a user? After reading up on OpenId Connect, it looks like you receive both an ID Token and an Access token upon success. But what if I don't care about authorization here. Can I omit the Access token from the protocol? Are there better protocols to use if I'm only interested in authentication (e.g. SAML)?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I found the answer on Access Token:

> UserInfo Endpoint
>
> It should be noted that clients are not required to use the access
>   token, since the ID Token contains all the necessary information for
>   processing the authentication event. However, in order to provide
>   compatibility with OAuth and match the general tendency for
>   authorizing identity and other API access in parallel, OpenID Connect
>   always issues the ID token along side an OAuth access token.

http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/